# Name of latest created GitHub file

Tags: javascript, html, github, github-api

First of all, sorry that I am new to web designing and *javascript*, and I hope that the answer could be elaborated, but I will appreciate any help.

I tried, in my own (small) website (by *GitHub*), to display a PDF file, which is easy. But when I am trying to get the newest file to display it, I failed. I found no code sample over the Internet, and so I turn to here to ask.

**How can I search in the *GitHub* repository to show the *LATEST* created file**?

I have been trying to read and understand something like [this documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api), but I don't understand **how it can be applied** in *javascript*. Where should I put the function at? And how can I input the directory content (including ***creation** date and time*) into some arrays of *javascript*? Sorry for asking these (possibly) stupid questions but I didn't find a related code sample over the Internet. **Can anyone help me with this? I would like to see some code samples, if possible.**

I would like to use *Javascript* (with *HTML*, of course) to achieve this, but I am really new to it, forgive me for that (I know programming **basics** in Python 3 and C++).

Any help will be appreciated.

### Edited with code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script text="type/javascript">
            var response = 
            await octokit.request('GET /repos/tonymayixuan/Introducing_Rigorous_Mathematics/contents/PDF/', {
                owner: 'tonymayixuan',
                repo: 'Introducing_Rigorous_Mathematics',
                path: 'PDF'
            })
            document.open();
            document.write(response);
            document.close();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to run the above but nothing is shown. May I ask how to record the "response" and use it?

Comment: What does your code currently look like? We can help diagnosing problems in your code, but we need to see it first!

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to use GitHub API inside javascript.

Comment: I was unable to find, over the internet, a description on GitHub API for getting file content in a directory (in repository).

Comment: Check this https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content

Comment: @gkulshrestha I just checked and updated my post, please have a look, thx!

Comment: @MattEllen I have updated my post with a piece of code, please check, thx!

Comment: Before you can access any content, I am sure you need to authenticate first. Please check the documentation on how you can do that.
Secondly, your code must be throwing errors. You can check in Browser's developer tools (pressing F12 should open it). This will help you understand where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

1. `await` cannot be used outside of an `async` function. (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).) The global scope is not an async function.
2. You don't seem to be importing the octokit library anywhere.

If you follow the examples at [octokit/rest.js](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18) you'll be able to do as you wish:

```html
<script type="module">
import { Octokit } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/@octokit/rest";
const octokit = new Octokit();
async function showFile()
{
const response = await octokit.request('GET /repos/tonymayixuan/Introducing_Rigorous_Mathematics/contents/PDF/', 
  {
    owner: 'tonymayixuan',
    repo: 'Introducing_Rigorous_Mathematics',
    path: 'PDF'
  });
  response.data.forEach(datum => document.write(datum.name+'<br>'));
}

showFile().then(_ => console.log('done'));
</script>
```